# Exponential Polar Form to a form of $a+bi$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH1K1.png)

So I'm wondering would I just need to expand the exponent meaning do $(\sqrt{2})^4$ and then multiply the $4$ in the exponent for e with the angle given? Thank you for the help, I apologize I don't have much experience with this page.

Comment: You are correct. If $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $z^4=r^4e^{4i\theta}$. Now use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to express it in the form $a+bi$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $z=re^{i\theta}$ then $z^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$. To convert it to the form $z=a+bi$ you just have to use Euler's formula: $re^{i\theta}=r\big(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\big)$ (and as a consequence $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $a=r\cos(\theta)$ and $b=r\sin(\theta)$)

Comment: Does this answer your question?